# What's the best way to describe our hobby's games?

Tags: discussion

I have heard the object of our hobby's affections called a number of things, none of which quite work for me. Failed descriptors include:

- Boardgames
- Eurogames
- German-style board games
- Hobby games

What do **you** call the games we love, the ones we mean when we talk about boardgames?

Comment: This seems like you just wanted to talk about the term "modern boardgames", and you tossed in a question at the end when you realized there wasn't one

Comment: Basically, you're right. I kept trying to find the question in this topic as I was typing. Whoever migrated this to meta - good job, thanks. I would have made it CW if I had the power, but I think this is a better solution!

Comment: np, I would still suggest rephrasing this to feature the question.  "Modern Boardgaming" feels like the answer that you would like to see to a question like, "What is the best name for our hobby?"

Comment: @Pat - Is that better?

Comment: @gomad - yes I think so, and I think this is a good question to ask.  I usually use "German-style" games, but would like something better.

Comment: Why was this moved to meta?

Comment: Two of your four options make me think that you are referring to only a subset of modern boardgames, but it's not clear what you mean.  Not all modern boardgames are German (or otherwise European), nor are they necessarily in that style.  Please list some games that you would include in the category you're trying to name.

Answer (score 8):

### Boardgames

Plain and simple. Though over here in Switzerland that term probably holds a much broader meaning in people's minds because we've known this type of games for decades now.

Thus the questions is highly dependent on your location. Overseas I'd probably use the term "German style boardgames" if I wanted to distinguish from games such as Chess or Monopoly. If that puts people off then that is unfortunate but ultimately their problem. This type of games was internationally popularized through German boardgames - a feat that justifies the naming. French cuisine is called as such even though it is now served all over the world.

Comment: Interesting points, thanks!  It's always great to get a wider perspective on things like this.

Comment: Agree.  With people who "know" what I mean, I say "board games" here in the States, but I am usually quick to clarify "German-style board games" if my audience is the type who will probably think of Monopoly or other family games (which then usually requires a 5-second definition).

Comment: Here in Italy they are just called "giochi da tavolo", i.e. "boardgames". Yes, the same term is used for the old-style boardgames, but this is not an issue. I also sometime call them "giochi nerd" ("nerd-games"): this might be instead confused with RPGs, but, again, that's not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

As a former retail store owner, I actually like the term **hobby games**.   It references the stores that these games first got their American foothold in (hobby stores), and the kind of store they're most often found.

I'm not as big a fan of calling them **eurogames** or **German boardgames** because a large number of them don't have those origins any more (Ex.: Most of the games coming from Z-Man).

On the use of "**modern boardgames**": Although this has a nice ring to it, I feel that "modern" is subjective. Is something that's been around for 20 years "modern"?  *Talisman*, *Illuminati*, and *Cosmic Encounter* are certainly hobby games, but they're also about 25 years old.

Comment: I have experience with the games you cite. I'm a huge *Illuminati* fan. I own and pretty much loathe *Cosmic Encounter*, and got rid of *Talisman* when I was in college. "A bag of gold!" is still an expression in my family that means, "Thanks for nothing!" Sure, they're not *Monopoly*, but I would never describe any of them as 'modern'. *Illuminati* comes closest - it has the use-it-to-build-it-as-you-use-it mechanic you find in *Puerto Rico* or *Agricola*. And like 'modern art', the phrase can cover a significant period of time and reflect philosophy as well as chronology.

Comment: "Hobby games" is my favourite suggestion so far.  Currently on the site we're discussing the likes Werewolf, Race for the Galaxy and Bridge... none of these have boards and they by no means all come out of Europe!

Answer (score 1):

### Modern Boardgames

I was watching the excellent "[beyond Monopoly][1]" themed video from [Boardgames With Scott][2], when I heard him use this new (to me at least) term to describe our hobby. I liked it a lot and I'm going to start using it regularly. Here are some reasons why:

1. If you don't differentiate from regular old **boardgames** somehow, people think you mean Monopoly and Sorry.
2. **Hobby Games** doesn't quite capture it for me. Chess and Go at the very least are long-standing hobby games, neither of which is what I mean.
3. **Eurogames / German Boardgames** have a couple of problems.

   1. It's not accurate any more - Lots of games are from the US now.
   2. It sounds snobby and puts people off. Seriously, I've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to call the games I enjoy as Euro Games. Whilst I appreciate that the origins of games are no longer purely european, the style and nature of these games definitely have evolved from the classic euro games, and have origins from UK, France and most predominantly Germany.

Although, your question is quite broad. Whilst the games I play are certainly in the Euro Game category, this site is for all board games, including the likes of monopoly, cluedo, pictionary and other younger audience games, but they certainly fall within the remit of this site. So I don't think you can categorise the whole site in any way other than saying **Boardgames**.

Boardgames to most people means Monopoly-esq games. But we know better in that it is the top of the taxonomy tree.

EuroGames/German Style/Modern boardgames means puerto rico / power grid style games, and is a subset of boardgames, and the ones most discussed in this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Boutique Boardgames**

Boutique: a business that serves a sophisticated or specialized clientele

Considering the small print runs of the games we are talking about, isn't this the best definition?

Comment: Magic the atheling and Dominion can't really be called small print runs

Answer (score 0):

**Designer Boardgames**

Since the games designer is featured proudly on the cover.
Since the games seem to have more thought devoted to the design (mechanics, theme, otherwise)