# Game Recommendation questions are banned

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic

With the agreement of the other moderators and the [unanimous consent of the voters here on meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/should-we-ban-game-recommendation-questions), game recommendations are banned.

#### Plan of Action

- Update the FAQ (done)
- Close all questions (done)
- Clean up comments on rec questions (in progress)
- Delete/fix/keep recommendation questions (TODO)

Note - Not every question is cut and dried for closing.  I've posted a few [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games), if you wish to jump in and give us some feedback on them, that would be great!

Some questions need to go (delete), some can be fixed and others we may want to keep for posterity locked with a moderator note saying something like, "This question is from long ago, and no longer meets the quality standards of this site.  Do not use this question as a template to form your own questions."

Comment: Heh, 4 of the 6 top voted questions are closed for this reason.  Perhaps delete them?  It looks really bad.

Comment: I think it might be nice if the FAQ would point to the previous meta discussion, which provides justification for what might seem like an arbitrary (and even unfriendly) rule to users not familiar with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @mattdm - hmmm, it's a fair point.  I'm thinking of linking it here, which links to the previous discussion.  Sound good?

Comment: @PatLudwig - Sure, whichever. :)